# Which is better: select with update, delete and insert, or replace?

Tags: mysql, select, replace, sql-insert, sql-delete

I've got a table `booking (id, date, interval)` and another table `booking_data (id, date, data)`, so I attach data in my `booking_data` table on `id` and `date` because my bookings are generated automatically, so when I want to insert data to avoid double insertion I have to use one of these methods:

1. `SELECT` and `INSERT` or `UPDATE` as necessary
2. `DELETE` by `id` and `date`, and then `INSERT`
3. `REPLACE` (I'm not sure about this whether has to have two keys or not and if has to have two my second can be the date.)

Which of these will be the best in my situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the possibilities has different tradeoffs, so there isn't a clear single answer. Some notes:

1. If you use `SELECT` followed by `INSERT` or `UPDATE`, you will need to use transactions `START TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT` or set `autocommit = 0`, and then use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` otherwise you may have conflicts with other transactions. This has the advantage though that you can potentially avoid doing anything if there are no conflicts.
2. Using `DELETE` followed by `INSERT` is manually doing exactly what `REPLACE` does. The `REPLACE` statement in a single statement and single transaction attempts to `INSERT` in a loop, and each time a key conflicts, it deletes the offending row. Doing this manually is more work both for you and the database and is trickier to implement correctly.